# Paypal Billing Agreement Validation error

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am trying to implement Billing using the Paypal REST API in Node.js But I encounter an error when I try to create the Billing Agreement. Looks like this:

```
{ [Error: Response Status : 400]
  response:
   { name: 'VALIDATION_ERROR',
     details: [ [Object] ],
     message: 'Invalid request - see details',
     information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR',
     debug_id: '484976af24de8',
     httpStatusCode: 400 },
  httpStatusCode: 400 }
```

First I tried to write billing plan and agreement following the documentation and then I tried to copy paste the sample code from github directly: [create a billing agreement](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/subscription/billing_agreements/create.js)

Creating the billing plan seems to work fine but when it is about to create the agreement it gives the error.

I have tried to change things around referencing the documentation but I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the start date provided while creating the agreement is a valid future date .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found out it was related to the start date formatting.

accepted formatting:
2016-01-01T15:50:59Z

not accepted:
2016-01-01T15:50:59.042Z

even though the latter can be seen in responses from the paypal API.